# How can I plot a image with (x,y,r,g,b) coordinates using ggplot2?

Tags: r, image-processing, plot, ggplot2, rgb

I have a data frame `image.rgb`, into which I have loaded the r,g,b value for each coordinate of an image (using the `jpeg` and `reshape` packages). It now looks like:

```
> head(image.rgb)
   y x         r         g         b
1 -1 1 0.1372549 0.1254902 0.1529412
2 -2 1 0.1372549 0.1176471 0.1411765
3 -3 1 0.1294118 0.1137255 0.1176471
4 -4 1 0.1254902 0.1254902 0.1254902
5 -5 1 0.1254902 0.1176471 0.1294118
6 -6 1 0.1725490 0.1372549 0.1176471
```

Now I want to plot this 'image' using ggplot2. I can plot a specific 'channel' (red or green or blue) **one** at a time using:

```
ggplot(data=image.rgb, aes(
            x=x, y=y,
            col=g) #green for example
       ) + geom_point()
```

...on the default ggplot2 colour scale

Is there a way to specify that the exact rgb values can be taken from the columns I specify?

Using the `plot` function in the `base` package, I can use

```
with(image.rgb, plot(x, y, col = rgb(r,g,b), asp = 1, pch = "."))
```

But I'd like to be able to do this using ggplot2

Comment: To clarify the structure of the data frame, for each (x,y) - within the range of image coordinates - there will exactly one entry in the dataframe (no more, no less)

Comment: What's wrong with `ggplot(data=image.rgb, aes(x=x, y=y, col=rgb(r,g,b))) + geom_point()` ? Seems to work here...

Comment: @juba rgb(r,g,b) creates a string value which is assigned an arbitrary colour by ggplot2 when passed to the col argument, not the actual rgb color indicated therein.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must add `scale_color_identity` in order for colors to be taken "as is" :

```
ggplot(data=image.rgb, aes(x=x, y=y, col=rgb(r,g,b))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_color_identity()
```

The sample data you provided give very similar colors, so all the points seem to be black. With `geom_tile` the different colors are a bit more visible :

```
ggplot(data=image.rgb, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=rgb(r,g,b))) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_raster()` is another option to consider.